# Principle of least benefit

Tags: macroeconomics, government

What is the name for the phenomenon/principle that a government subsidy or other benefit, tends to fail to reach the people that need it the most or for whom it was intended?

The reason being that the knowledge that the subsidy exists is found more in those who are well off to begin with, while the most poor or marginalized are not in the position to learn about it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a name for it. I would just say that there is an information cost. What I mean by this is that you can either pay someone who knows the information to reveal it to you or you can take time to find it yourself, which carries the opportunity cost of your time. For example, many complain that the rich pay less in taxes because they have accountants who know the loopholes and the tax codes backwards and forwards. Now, regular citizens can learn this information (it is publicly available), but there is an opportunity cost because it would take a lot of time to learn all of it